# Form Wizard can't access final "done" step

Tags: python, django, forms, django-models, django-forms

I'm using Django 3 and I try to implement a basic "example" Wizard Form from django-forms.

**My Problem is :**
1/ can't retrieve inputs from previous forms steps
2/ can't access to "done.html" after submitting last steps

Here's my code :

views.py

```
class ContactWizard(SessionWizardView):
    template_name = 'accounts/test_wizard.html'
    form_list = [ContactForm1, ContactForm2, ContactForm3]
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        form_data = process_form_data(form_list)
        return render(self.request, 'accounts/done.html', {'form_data': form_data})


def process_form_data(form_list):
    form_data = [form.cleaned_data for form in form_list]
    return(form_data)
```

urls.py

```
from forms.models import ContactForm1, ContactForm2, ContactForm3
from .views import ContactWizard

urlpatterns = [
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('login/', views.login, name='login'),
    path('logout/', views.logout, name='logout'),
    path('profile/', views.profile, name='profile'),
    path('test_wizard/', ContactWizard.as_view([ContactForm1, ContactForm2, ContactForm3]), name='test_wizard'),
]
```

forms.py (actually, I'm using a forms/models.py to have a separate app for forms. But it seems to be ok as I see all forms.

```
class ContactForm1(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(max_length=250)

class ContactForm2(forms.Form):
    sender = forms.EmailField()

class ContactForm3(forms.Form):
    message = forms.CharField(max_length=250)
```

Thanks in advance guys for your help !